Plotting qualitative data in a barplot, where there are 42 factors
I have a dataset about hoverflies. I want a barplot where the number of hoverflies are plotted against the month in which they have been caught. Additionally, I want to show which abundance the genera/species make up in this. This can be done by colour. The graph I already was given shows this in a sequential pattern, making it impossible to infer what species is corresponding to what part.
I do not exactly know how to produce a sample of the dataset, but it has a columns Genus, Species, SampleID CorCounts and Months. The rows are the species found in every sample (so they do duplicate).
All %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Months, y = MeanMonth, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Average number of hoverfly genera by month") +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.key.height = unit(0.4, 'cm'), legend.text=element_text(size=8)) + labs(x="Month",y="Average number of hoverflies")


I already saw possibilities of producing palettes with more colours at R color palettes for many data classes. However, I am unable to incorporate this. I tried creating P42 = createPalette(42,  c("#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff")), and adding + scale_fill_manual(values = P42, aesthetics = "fill") and + scale_fill_manual(values = P42) to the plotting code. However, this yielded in the error:
Warning messages:
1: No shared levels found between `names(values)` of the manual scale and the data's fill values. 
2: No shared levels found between `names(values)` of the manual scale and the data's fill values. 

How can I generate the plot with the colour scheme more clear? Additionally, if possible, is there a way to define how many genera are put below eachother in the legenda (so that it can fill the space a bit more efficiently, decreasing the relative size of the legenda whilst still being readable)?

There's probably a way to achieve this layout. However, small multiples, ridge plots or sparklines are definitely worth considering as alternatives.

These are very good suggestions and I definetely will try them out from time to time. However, due to the high number of genera/species and the low number of factors (months) both the multiples and the ridge plots do not really work out. Many thanks though!

This would be a technical solution to your question, drawing from the best-voted answer to this similar question:

create some play data (mind to provide such next time), here I'm querying Wikidata for Syrphidae genera and species, taking the species count per genus as a surrogate for abundancy and faking a seasonal distribution similar to yours:

    library(WikidataQueryServiceR)

    All <- 
      '
      SELECT
        ?genusLabel ?speciesLabel
      WHERE {
        ?genus wdt:P171 wd:Q217905.
        ?species wdt:P171 ?genus.
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } 
      }
    ' |> 
      query_wikidata() |> 
      count(genusLabel) |> head(42) |> 
      rowwise() |> 
      mutate(n = list(n * c(May = .1, June = .2, July = .6, Aug = .08, Sep = .02))) |> 
      unnest_longer(n) |>
      rename(Genus = genusLabel, Months = n_id, MeanMonth = n) |> 
      mutate(Months = forcats::fct_relevel(Months, c('May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep')))


result:

    > head(All)
    # A tibble: 6 × 3
      Genus        MeanMonth Months
      <chr>            <dbl> <fct> 
    1 Afromicrodon      0.4  May   
    2 Afromicrodon      0.8  June  
    3 Afromicrodon      2.4  July  
    4 Afromicrodon      0.32 Aug   
    5 Afromicrodon      0.08 Sep   
    6 Agnisyrphus       0.2  May 



create multicolored bar chart (credits to JelenaČuklina for how to build the palette):

library(RColorBrewer)

qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))


All %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Months, y = MeanMonth, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c('May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_vector) +
  ggtitle("Average number of hoverfly genera by month")


However, I think there are several ways to help the reader grasp the information more quickly, e. g.

a facetted plot, partitioning the genera by MonthMean like so:

All_classed <- 
  All |> 
    mutate(Genus_Max = max(MeanMonth), .by = Genus) |> 
    mutate(Group = as.integer(cut(log(Genus_Max), 6)))


All_classed |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Months, y = MeanMonth, group = Genus)) +
    geom_line(color = 'darkgrey') +
    geom_text_repel(data = All_classed |> filter(Months == 'July'),
                    aes(Months, MeanMonth, label = sprintf('%s (%.0f)', Genus, MeanMonth)),
                    hjust = 0
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~ Group, scales = 'free_y')


(Note that the first panel has no labels, as it contains too many monospecific genera to separately label with geom_text_repel.)

a sparkline table:

library(gt)
library(gtExtras)

All |>
  summarise(MeanMonth = list(MeanMonth), .by = Genus) |>
  gt() |> 
  gtExtras::gt_plt_sparkline(column = MeanMonth, same_limit = FALSE)




or you might find that your genera have very similar seasonal trends anyway, differing only in absolute numbers. In that case you might scale MeanMonth per genus, plot them all as a bundle of lines and only annotate the absolute values at peak season, e.g. with geom_text_repel.


Wow, thanks for your extensive help. I am going to try out these, but they are certainly very helpful. Thanks a lot!
